# TextView не меняется текст

Tags: android, java

Есть код, по хандлеру должен меняться текст в текствью, но при запуску приложение вылетает

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
        text.setText("Text2");
                    }
                }, 4000);
```

Comment: в будущем указывайте лог из LogCat, когда говорите, что что-то "вылетает".    
А то тут одни ясновидящие...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, верхнюю строчку написал выше `onCreate`, так же не указал `TextView text;` и немного подправил

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```